# FATAL ERROR: Reached heap limit Allocation failed - JavaScript heap out of memory(i have set the max-old-space-size already) discord.js node.js

Tags: node.js, discord.js

I keep getting this error, I have set my `max-old-space-size` to `8192` or higher and I don't understand what is the problem.

I have tried various types of size too.

This is the main part of the code:

```
client.on("message", message =>{
    let i = 1;
    while (i < 10) {
        task(i)
    }
    function task(i) {
        setTimeout(function (){
            util.statusBedrock('ip', { port: port, timeout: 3800})
            .then((reponse) =>{
                const Embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
                .setColor('#62ff00')
                .setTitle('Server Status')
                .setAuthor('Made by ThatTheredstoner')
                .addField(':green_circle: Online', reponse.version)
                .addField('**Software/System**', reponse.software)
                .addField('Server IP', 'ip')
                .addField('Server Port', reponse.port)
                .addField('Gamemode', 'Survival ')
                .addField('**Latency**', reponse.roundTripLatency)
                .addField('Online Player', reponse.onlinePlayers)
                .addField('Player', reponse.players)
                .addField('Max Players', reponse.maxPlayers)
                .setTimestamp()
                .setFooter('footer');
                        
                client.channels.cache.get('channel').messages.fetch('message').then((mesg)=>{
                    mesg.edit(Embed);
                })
                console.log(reponse);
            })
            .catch((error) => {
                console.log(error)
                const OEmbed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
                .setColor('#ff0000')
                .setTitle('Server Status')
                .setAuthor('Powered with Redstone')
                .addField(':red_circle:', 'Offline')
                .addField('Server IP', 'ip')
                .setTimestamp()
                .setFooter('footer');
                                
                client.channels.cache.get('channel id').messages.fetch('message id').then((mesg)=>{
                    mesg.edit(OEmbed);
                })  
            })
        }, 4000);
    }
});
```

I swapped out the IDs and IPs for good measurement.

Comment: this package is minecraft-server-util btw

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is within your while loop. Variable `i` is never used or updated. Because of your logic in the while loop, variable `i` is always below `10` no matter what.

Because of the never ending loop, and every time someone posts a message, your while loop will stack until there is no memory left on your machine to execute your `while()` loop, thus it will collapse and crash your application.

My solution would be as followed: Put your async task outside of the message loop and make a trigger command for it, for example `!update server info`.

`!` My answer might divergent from your own code, I've made a simulation for an async task as following:

```js
let isBusy = false;
const tasks = 10;
const asyncTask = (ms, i) => new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(() => {
    console.log(`Task (${i}) finished in ${ ms / 1000 } seconds.`);
    resolve(true);
}, ms));

client.on("message", async message => {
    if(message.content === "!update server info") {

        if(isBusy === false) {
            isBusy = true;
            let i = 0;
            while(i++ < tasks) {
                await asyncTask(Math.floor(Math.random() * 5000), i); // THE MATH CALCULATION ON THIS LINE IS TO SIMULATE AN ASYNC TASK! DO NOT USE IN YOUR CODE.
                if(i >= tasks) isBusy = false;
            }
        }else{
            // Send a message to the user if your tasks are still running or not.
        }
    }
});
```

Also in your case you're updating your message frequently, I wouldn't do that as it may result in a rateLimit error. I would update your message only once per 1 or 2 minutes.

`!` This answer might not ideal or best practice, but it should push you to the right direction and understand how `while` loops work.

Comment: ok, thx for the advice, i am always bad with while loops and other loops, :)

Answer (score 3):

Not an answer to the ops question but since this is the top search result for that error message here's an answer for other people who may be using **create-react-app**.

To change the heap limit for react-scripts you need to do it in `package.json` by changing the build line to:

```
"build": "react-scripts --max_old_space_size=4096 build"
```

Attempts to set environment variables, add parameters to the node command all seem ineffective but changing it here in package.json works.